# AS3 Error 2038 on Windows only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, upload, filereference, ioerror

hope someone can help me with this!

I've written a simple online 3d editor in Flash - it's about to go out to a selection of clients but the file uploader has a bit of a glitch which has only just reared its ugly head. Using FileReference to upload media to https page, it works like a dream on OSX which is what it was built on, but on Windows it's returning Error 2038 on every browser. Has anyone encountered this before?

Any help much appreciated!

```
public class CustomFileReferenceList extends FileReferenceList {

    private var uploadURL:URLRequest;
    private var pendingFiles:Array;

    public static var length:int = 0;
    public static var arrLen:int = 0;

    public function CustomFileReferenceList() {
        uploadURL = new URLRequest();
        uploadURL.url = "https://___";
        var rqd:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        uploadURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        rqd.sessionId = Main.sessionId;
        uploadURL.data = rqd;
        initializeListListeners();
    }

    private function initializeListListeners():void {
        addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
        addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelHandler);
    }

    private function doOnComplete():void {
        //var event:Event = new Event(Uploader.LIST_COMPLETE);
        //dispatchEvent(event);
enter code here
    }

    private function addPendingFile(file:FileReference):void {
        pendingFiles.push(file);
        file.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler,false,0,true);
        file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler,false,0,true);
        file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler,false,0,true);
        file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler,false,0,true);
        file.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler,false,0,true);
        file.upload(uploadURL);
    }

    private function removePendingFile(file:FileReference):void {
        for (var i:uint; i < pendingFiles.length; i++) {
            if (pendingFiles[i].name == file.name) {
                pendingFiles.splice(i, 1);
                if (pendingFiles.length == 0) {
                    doOnComplete();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private function selectHandler(event:Event):void {


        arrLen = length = fileList.length;
        pendingFiles = new Array();
        var file:FileReference;
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            file = FileReference(fileList[i]);
            addPendingFile(file);
        }
    }

    private function cancelHandler(event:Event):void {
        //var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
    }

    private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
    }

    private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
    }

    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
        length--;
        removePendingFile(file);
    }

    private function httpErrorHandler(event:Event):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:Event):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:Event):void {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can promise you FileReference works on windows. Post the relevant code your using.

Comment: I know, I've used it before on Windows, I'm just using:

(This is a class to upload multiple files sequentially)

pendingFiles.push(file);
file.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler,false,0,true);
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler,false,0,true);
file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioErrorHandler,false,0,true);
file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,progressHandler,false,0,true);   file.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,securityErrorHandler,false,0,true);
   
file.upload(uploadURL);

This works on OSX but always gets IO_ERROR on windows...

Comment: does your upload script return anything? After a successful upload, echo something out like "success". I've had issues where if the upload script (I use PHP) didn't output anything, it would fail on certain browsers/machines

Comment: Edit your answer to include code where you create the `file` object

Comment: Yeah it chucks out XML response 200, strange that this issue is confined to Windows, figured it might be a problem with uploading the file from the system but looks to be a problem with xferring it, driving me mental!

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices

   
for (var i:uint = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
 file = FileReference(fileList[i]);
 addPendingFile(file);
}

Comment: Can you please post your upload script? You can hide any information, like domains if you like

Comment: Added to main question, thanks a million for this

Comment: Sorry, I meant your server side script, not the AS3. Although both help us help you

Comment: I didn't write it and I don't currently have access to it, I can get hold but not at the moment(!)

Comment: Hmm ok. Well, I think the server side upload script (not the as3 script) should output something on a successful upload. For me, Macs were having an issue that if the server side script didn't output anything, it would throw an error. Also, googling around, I found a person with the same issue you are having where it doesn't work on windows, but it works on mac: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?268410-file-upload-returns-ioError-2038 --Looks like adding an htaccess with `secfiltering` options fixed it

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow - you are a star mate, thanks so much

Comment: yeah post back what you come up with..I am curious

Comment: It might have something to do with different endian values on Mac and Windows, IIRC MacOS has big endian everywhere, while Windows has little endian. So, when you upload a file from some variable, convert it into a ByteArray first, then check what endian works, and if different, change it to that endian settings with that ByteArray, and only then invoke upload.

Comment: @Vesper it does look like you're right about that, was about to try when the solution came out of nowhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying just about every solution, the other web dev found it worked ok minus fancy url names i.e referencing ourserver/thepage.php instead of ourserver/service. Absolutely crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I have today this issue, in my case, I was be trace of the length of the source (url/nativePath) and the length of destin; I was found that the length of the destin url is up to 256 characters.

To solve this, I was be changed the destin point (with simbolic link or network drive)

Example:

```
// MAC remote path
var mSt:String  = "file:////MacBook-Pro-de-Jaime.local/Seagate/netShared/transport-machines/SoftDepot/";

// Windows Remote Drive (\\MacBook-Pro-...\transport-machines)
// Remote MAC as Windows Drive N
var mSt:String  = "file:///N:/SoftDepot/";
```

Voila, the new name reduces several characers.